# Ubuntu shows that i'm in offline mode while trying to connect to internet

Tags: networking, internet

I have lenovo Z580 laptop and dual-booted my system with windows 8 and ubuntu 13.04. I can connect to internet using windows 8(both wired & wireless) but cannot connect using ubuntu(both). It always shows me that "I am in offline mode"

Comment: have you installed latest updates?

Comment: I tried solution and this is the reply: 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

Comment: @UbuntuUser I recommend seeing this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/7035 Take it easy, read carefully and you should have a working Wireless card in no time. The one you have is the same one I have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your laptop might use the infamous Broadcom chipset 14e4:4727, which needs special attention.

From http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2092561,

Try running

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

If your device is the Broadcom 14e4:4727, then run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

To re-install the drivers. Then reboot and try the connection again.